# Use module-based serialization in another codebase where I don't control ObjectMapper construction

Tags: java, scala, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I maintain a Scala library that successfully uses all the automatic `jackson-module-scala` functionality in its own home context, where I control the construction of `ObjectMapper`s.

Now, I'm trying to use the same library as a dependency in an off-the-shelf codebase that constructs `ObjectMapper`s in its own way, so I can't bring in the Scala module in the usual way--the module is on the classpath but isn't used.

Is ther some way to invoke the ser/des functionality provided by the Scala module *explicitly*, e.g. using annotations?

e.g.:

#### Scala library

I have DTO classes like this:

```scala
@JsonNaming(classOf[SnakeCaseStrategy])
case class Foo(
  bar: String,
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "UTC", lenient = OptBoolean.TRUE)
  timestamp: Instant,
  bazId: Option[UUID]
)
```

And this is my ObjectMapper:

```scala
object JSON {
  val objectMapper: JsonMapper with ClassTagExtensions = JsonMapper.builder()
    .addModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)
    .build() :: ClassTagExtensions
}
```

and they're used like this:

```scala
val s: String = ???

val foo: Foo = JSON.objectMapper.readValue[Foo](s)
```

#### Runtime Context

In the runtime context, ObjectMappers are created with a mixture of  dependency injection and hardcoding that I can't see any way to customize.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this, which delegates to the Scala module

```scala
val scalaModule = ???

class ScalaModuleSerializer[T] extends JsonSerializer[T] {
  override def serialize(value: T, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider): Unit = {
    scalaModule.serialize(value, gen, serializers)
  }
}

class FooSerializer extends ScalaModuleSerializer[Foo]
```

...then inject `FooSerializer` at runtime somehow.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do and what is exactly the issue. You have your own lib that depends on jackson, then you have a project that depends on your lib. I would imagine that the lib you created cover the needs of the project. Could you clarify the problem? Maybe show some code of what you have and what you can't achieve could help

Comment: Added some context, thanks!